# Display thumbnail of child images in grouped product page

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

I created a grouped product, each child product has an image but they do not get displayed in on the front. No you only see the product name, price, quantity,...
[image]

Is there an easy way to do this? thanks.

Comment: Do you want to show child product images in place of group product image? If yes then how do you show multiple product images in single place?

Comment: No I want to show the images of each product, I'm going to edit my question so it's more clear.

Comment: You mean under child product's table?

Comment: Yes see my edit

Comment: After the product name or before the product name?

Comment: I prefer before but it doesn't really matter now.

Comment: Can you please check  my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the following file:

> vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

to:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

and use the below code for it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>

<?php $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository'); ?>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
            <?php $childProduct = $productRepository->get($_item->getSku()); ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="<?= $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$childProduct->getImage() ?>"/></td>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                    <div class="sku"><?= $_item->getSku() ?></div>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                    <div class="control qty">
                        <input type="number"
                               name="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               data-selector="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                               title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                               data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))): ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>
```

I have used object manager which is not a good practice. You need to override the block file and then add your code accordingly.

Comment: the file was not **group.phtml** but **grouped.phtml** but It still worked thanks.

Comment: Yes right. Typo mistake. I have updated it.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, Thanks, It's working like a charm..!